# running three processes in docker and last .py file not found not found

Tags: docker

I created a docker file that is supposed to run three processes sequentially: a.py, b.py, c.py. They are all saved in the main folder (`/root/my_docker/`) in parallel with the bin folder (where build_container.sh and run_container.sh are located), and lib folder (where other necessary scripts are located). I created a main code (d.sh) just like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
a.py && b.py && c.py
```

which is located parallel to  a.py, b.py, c.py and should run them in sequence. However, although it runs a.py and b.py smoothly, it stops before running c.py and shows the following error message:

```
/root/my_docker/d.sh: 3: /root/my_docker/d.sh: c.py: not found
```

And I checked several times that c.py exists in the specified folder.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: use absolute path instead and it will work

Comment: what is the first line of each a.py, b.py and c.py? (the line that starts with `#!...`)

Comment: First lines are  #!/usr/bin/env python

Answer (score 0):

To avoid path issues and chmod issues, pass them to the python interpreter:

```
#!/bin/sh
python a.py && python b.py && python c.py
```

And to avoid missing files in the future, you can use wildcard:

```
COPY *.py /root/my_docker/
```

Comment: I did a chmod fix on c.py, but did not help with this particular peroblem. As to tyour suggestion, not yet. I am still getting...  python: can't open file 'c.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: can you please try this? `python a.py && python b.py && ls -la`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  65 root root 4096 May 29 20:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  65 root root 4096 May 29 20:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Mar 20 23:40 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 15 22:00 boot
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  374 May 29 19:08 data

Comment: This was just part of the output.

Comment: How can the first and second work, but the third don't? Odd.Have you tried absolute paths? `python /root/my_docker/c.py`

Comment: Ok, I found the problem and it was my fault. I had forgotten to update the dockerfile with:   COPY c.py /root/my_docker/

Comment: Ok, we've got confused because you said `And I checked several times that c.py exists in the specified folder.` !

Comment: Yeap. I got confused as well. I am still getting used with the specific docker jargon. The file was in my local folder, but not in the "virtual" docker folder. Appologies, and hope my problem helps other users.